# Show there are p-1 ordered pair solutions of $y^2≡x^2-a\pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory

I begin with a similar problem as here,
[Ordered pair solutions of x2-y2≡a(modp)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335257/ordered-pair-solutions-of-x2-y2-equiv-a-pmod-p), only my question regards the first part: Let $p ∈\mathbb{N} $ be an odd prime, $p > 3$. Let a ∈ $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p\nmid a$.show there are $p-1$ solutions $(x,y)$ to $y^2 \equiv x^2-a\pmod{p}$. I have a solution below. But namely, I don't understand the logic of the last two statements in the proof, if someone could please help explain them to me in more detail?

1. $uv \equiv -a\pmod{p} \implies$ u, v coprime to p
2. Because for each u coprime to p, we can solve for v uniquely mod p $\implies$ there are exactly p−1 solutions.

---

Solution: The initial congruence is equivalent to $$(y − x)(y + x) ≡ −a\pmod{p}$$ Let $$u = y − x, v = y + x$$
Since p is odd, we can solve uniquely for x and y in terms of u and v mod p: $$x=\frac{v−u}{2}, y =\frac{u+v}{2}$$
So the number of solutions to the original congruence is the same as the number of solutions to
the congruence $$uv ≡ −a\pmod{p}$$ Clearly, u and v must be coprime to p. For each u coprime
to p, we can solve for v uniquely mod p. So there are exactly p−1 solutions to this congruence
mod p.

Comment: If, say, $p\,|\,u$ then $uv\equiv 0\pmod p$ but $a\not \equiv 0\pmod p$.  And there are $p-1$ possible choices for $u$ prime to $p$.

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks @lulu